# Ajax working perfect on Desktop but not on phones/Tablet

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been trying to put this to work both on desktop and phones, but the problem is that the Ajax that I have on the site, just works well on the desktop, not on the phones/tablets, either is on iphone or android, several browsers where tested and still doesn't work on phone/tablet.

here is the code

```
$(function() {
    $('.navmenu a').bind('click', function(event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disableLink'))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var urlToGo = $(this).attr('href');
            if (!$(this).attr('id'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlToGo,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $(".container").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var dataToPass = {tipo : $(this).attr('id'), nome : $(this).text()}
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: urlToGo,
                    data: dataToPass,
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $(".container").html(result);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        if ($( window ).width() <= "992" && !$(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle'))
        {
            $('.navmenu').offcanvas('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

What is wrong in here, the one on the IF works without any problem, but when I try to use the POST doesn't work on phone/table but perfect on desktops

Comment: Tricky to say without seeing the format of urlToGo. Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942292/ajax-function-will-not-work-on-mobile-browser) of any help? It goes through a few potential causes.

Comment: @colonelsanders the format is basicly like www.example.com/filetoload.php its what will be the urlToGo

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the problem was with jasny bootstrap, it as a bug that will be fixed on the next version, and the work arround is by adding this .navmenu-nav.dropdown-menu { position: relative; } to the css of the page.